# database structure - how do I know I need multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

How do you know if data should be in a separate table or all clumped into one table per product? Is there a general rule or best practice?

For example.

A product has a name, brand, classifications, directions, warnings, a recommended use,  comments, notes, restrictions.

I could see how they could all benefit from separate tables but could it work just as well with comma separated entries all under one table of products?

How do you know if a relational database is overkill or essential?

Comment: If you store a CSV in a column, there's a very good chance you will make any future programmers who have to manipulate the data very angry.

Comment: would be safe to say that more tables the more flexible?

Comment: More tables make it a lot easier to write powerful queries and have useful indexes at the expense of making it a little more work to insert the data.

Comment: if you want to use CSV, use files and not a relational database

Comment: If you're designing a relational database, one row per product all in one table would be closer to a basic design. Whether you need to decompose this table for the sake of normalization is another matter. One table per product isn't even relational.

Answer (score 5):

If you're considering storing comma separated lists of anything, then it's a clear sign you need to break it out into another table.  Never store more than one value per column.

Please read this for more info on database normalization:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

To further elaborate, designing a good database schema can feel a bit like an art -- with time and experience you will get better at it.  Don't worry so much about making mistakes that you're afraid to try things.

But also realize that relational database theory has been around for more than 30 years and a lot of pain can be avoided by learning about standard ways of doing things.

Comment: something like a brand which has many products should be in table of its own? With a brandID and name while the products table has productID name and brandID... How do you know if an entry should be a part of a table or in its own table?

Comment: In this case I can see how it's maybe more of a grey area.  Is a product only going to ever have one and only one brand?  If you want to allow for products with multiple brands then a separate table makes sense.  How about having to update the brand name?  If you stored the name with each record, then updating the brand means updating every product record as well.  But here I can see how you might not need either of those things, so maybe here it's ok to just store the name with each record.  The clearer you define the requirements for the system, the easier these questions are to answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re comma-separating values, then that’s a good time to move data into another table.

Once your data is neatly-organised into tables that contain specific types of data, then it makes things selecting records easier.

For example, tags. Yes, you could save tags as a CSV in your products table, but then how do you fetch all products tagged "utility"? You’d have to select all records, split the tags into an array at the comma, and then iterate through your products collection for relavant ones. This is just one example. I’m sure you can see how this only grows the more records and more complex data you store.

Comment: And in your tag example, it would be pretty much impossible to have a useful index on the tags. So pretty much every search would be incredibly slow.

Comment: something like a brand which has many products should be in table of its own? With a brandID and name while the products table has productID name and brandID... How do you know if an entry should be a part of a table or in its own table?

Comment: @chris I think you need to look into foreign keys. If you are storing brands, they should be in their own table. Then you store a relation between the product and a brand, as a product can have many brands, and a brand can have many products.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee Care to elaborate on your response and provide an example as to why tags in their own table is such a bad thing, and how you would store tags and tagged data yourself?

Comment: @MartinBean you misinterpreted what I said. I supported (and upvoted) your answer. I was providing an additional reason to support your hypothetical situation.

Comment: i think @Geoff_Montee's example was referring to the scenario of tags being separated by commas in one field instead of in their own table.

Comment: @chris exactly. Thanks. I should have been more specific. I should have said *And in your tag CSV example, it would be pretty much impossible to have a useful index on the tags.*

Comment: @Geoff_Montee would you really have to split the tags into an array and iterate through each separation? There's no simpler way to search a CSV field for a given value?

Comment: @chris not quite. If you were to store a CSV in a field, you could use the `LIKE` operator in SQL to search it. But you couldn't really have a useful index to help you with that.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee that's what I thought. So it's not really a huge deal minus the lack of index as long as the csv list doesn't go too long. Correct? I wanna be somewhat flexible but I don't want to complicate the db for a few exceptions.

Comment: @chris I always dislike CSVs because it complicates application code and queries. However, separating it out into a new table adds another table to deal with, and more work when doing inserts. The developer just has to pick which tradeoffs are better for their situation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19054/discussion-between-chris-and-geoff-montee)

Comment: @Geoff_Montee Ah, I see. I thought that comment was in response to my tags example. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have redundant data in your table that's a sign that you will need to create new tables.  In the example you used above with products:

> A product has a name, brand, classifications, directions, warnings, a
>   recommended use, comments, notes, restrictions.

The classifications would be a clear item that you would want listed in another table.  This makes your data normalized.  So in the above example I would have at least three tables, one for brand, one for classifications, and one for products.  If you need multiple notes and track different times when notes were added then you can create a table for that.  This makes it easy to look up data, ensures that if for example you want to re-classify all widgets in the widgetgroup classification you will only have to update the name of the group in the classification table and not every record in the products table.

Here is a link to the topic on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to know whether you need a different table for each product. This is definitely not how database normalization works.

You want to separate tables based on their types (called "entities" in the database world).

Your example seems fairly trivial. I'm not sure where you planned to use CSVs. However, I'm unsure if some of these fields have very structured values (what constitutes a "classification" or a "warning"?).

But anyway, a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE brand (
    brand_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    brand_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    brand_id INT,
    classifications VARCHAR(200),
    directions VARCHAR(200), 
    warnings VARCHAR(200), 
    recommended_use VARCHAR(200),
    comments VARCHAR(200),
    notes VARCHAR(200),
    restrictions VARCHAR(200)
);
```

And then if you wanted to query all **Sony** products, you would do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product
JOIN brand
USING (brand_id)
WHERE brand_name = 'Sony';
```

If some of your other fields in the `product` table are more structured, you would want to split them out just like you did for `brand`.

So if `warnings`, `classifications`, etc. have very structured values (or more than one value for each product), you should really put them into a new table.

I'm unsure of what you plan to do with those other fields. So let me give a concrete example of a made-up field that is commonly used.

Lets assume that you want to keep track of the `category` of products. Some would use a CSV of category names in the `product` table for this.

However, you could have two more tables:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
    category_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE product_category (
    product_id INT,
    category_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(product_id, category_id)
);
```

So products can have multiple categories by having multiple entries in the `product_category` table.

So if you wanted to search for `Sony` `Electronics`:

```
SELECT product.* 
FROM product
JOIN brand
USING (brand_id)
JOIN product_category
USING (product_id)
JOIN category
USING (category_id)
WHERE brand_name = 'Sony'
AND category_name = 'Electronics';
```

And this would return products that might be TVs, DVD players, stereo systems, etc.

Comment: this is what i ment by flexible yes. Seems more complex for simple queries but I can see how it would be healthier in the long run.

Comment: is it often the case that many small tables is better practice than fewer large tables. As in should I be looking to break down my data into types as much as possible even if I dont foresee multiple entries of the exact same type? Example warnings would have their own table even though there's a possibility that no two warnings are used on the same product.

Comment: @chris I wouldn't assume that. You may want to try both possibilities and run some benchmarks using your DBMS of choice.

Comment: are queries with so many joins a hard hit on the db or recommendation of you're?

Comment: @chris depends on the DBMS you are using, the size of the tables involved, and how many rows match the `JOIN` criteria. You should really run some benchmarks against the SQL and data that your application will use.